# Regex matching things i don't want to again

Tags: php, regex, preg-match

I asked a similar question yesterday but I am still lacking the knowledge of some parts of regex to follow.

Anyway I have this string:

```
[[{{6^-2}}x{{6^3}}|{{6^-2}}]]
```

I want to match the following regex:

```
\[\[(.*?)\^(.*?)\]\]
```

So basically wanting to isolate if this string has [[anything^anything]]

It works to an extent, but it's also matching becuase the are the `^` symbol in there. I don't want this to match those, this expression shouldn't match because the symbol is `|` not `^` between the square brackets.

Basically it should be ignoring the parts inside the {}

**EDITS TO MAKE MORE SENSE:**

Example String: [[{{hello^test}}|{{goodbye}}]]
My Pattern: [[(.*?)\^(.*?)]]
Expected Match: False because i want to only match the ^ if it's part of the outside part of the string surrounded by [[ ]] not if it's inside the {{ }}

Example String: [[{{hello^test}}^{{goodbye}}]]
My Pattern: [[(.*?)\^(.*?)]]
Expected Match: True because both sides of the ^ inside [[ ]] match, ignoring what is inside the {{ }}

Example String: [[{{hello^test}}^{{goodbye^test}}]]
My Pattern: [[(.*?)\^(.*?)]]
Expected Match: True because again the ^ is between the two parts in {{ }} and needs to ignore what is inside {{ }}

Example String: [[{{hello^test}}|{{goodbye^test}}]]
My Pattern: [[(.*?)\^(.*?)]]
Expected Match: False because there is no ^ inside the [[ ]] only inside the {{ }} which should be ignored

My pattern isn't working because it's also picking up the ^ symbol inside the {{ }} and matching either side of it , i need it to match either side of the ^ which is wrapped in the [[ ]] not the {{ }}

I hope that makes sense..

Comment: What is your expected output?

Comment: in this case it shouldn't match because there isn't a ^ symbol inside the [[ ]] it's a | symbol it shouldn't be matching the ^ inside the {{ }}

Comment: basically need the pattern to ignore the {{x^x}} bits and only match if the strinng is say [[whatever^whatever]]

Comment: @GlenElkins So does `whatever` always have this format `{{something inside}}` ?

Comment: Edited the question , hopefully makes more sense

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
\[\[(\{\{.+?\}\}|[^^{}]+)\^(.+?)\]\]
```

**Explanation:**

```
\[\[            # 2 opening square brackets
(               # start group 1
    \{\{        # 2 opening curly braces
    .+?         # 1 or more any character, not greedy
    \}\}        # 2 closing curly braces
  |             # OR
    [^^{}]+     # 1 or more NON carret or curly braces
)               # end group 1
\^              # a carret
(.+?)           # group 2, 1 or more any characters, not greedy
\]\]            # 2 closing square brackets
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/gOQZ19/3)

Comment: Doesn't work mate, on regexr nothing is matching if i change the | to ^

Comment: @GlenElkins: Please, [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/55100906/edit) and add some test cases.

Comment: Edited the question , hopefully makes more sense

Comment: @GlenElkins: Does this correct for you: https://regex101.com/r/gOQZ19/2

Comment: it does on your example but not on this : [[{{6^-2}}x{{6^3}}|{{6^-2}}]]

Comment: @GlenElkins: Sorry, I don't get you. Must it match or not?

Comment: Actually yes it does work! The example i gave it's not supposed to match but if i change | to ^ it matches

Answer (score 0):

Try this pattern: `^[^{]*(?=({.*?(?1)?.*?})*[^{]*\^).+$`

It uses recrusion to assure that `^` character won't be inside curly braces. Instead of explaining the whole regex, I recommend reading about regex recursion (for example [here](https://www.rexegg.com/regex-recursion.html)). Then the regex will be easy to understand.

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/WdFPe4/1)

Comment: See on RegExr that doesn't match anything either, i tried it on this string: [[{{6^-2}}x{{6^3}}^{{6^-2}}]] and it doesn't match anything when it should because there is a ^ inside the [[ ]] with {{ }} either side of it

Comment: I just tested it on: Work out the value of [[{{6^-2}}x{{6^3}}|{{6^-2}}]] with preg_match in php and it's not matching it